# Is fracture voronoi breaking my surface?

Tags: modeling, cinema4d

[image]

when I use fracture voronoi on any round object (sphere, pill, torus...), the surface of the material get fragmented like the image above (phong tag isnt the cause). When I tried to subdiv the fragments are still there, just got smaller, but when tuning subdiv down to **zero**, the problem is gone (image bellow), I have no clue what happens, please send help, thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried applying that material to anything else?  Make another taurus, but this time don't make it editable (don't press C).  See if the material gets applied the same way.  It looks to me like it could be an issue with your UVW tag telling the material to be applied to each polygon individually, instead of the taurus as a whole, but I haven't used C4D in years, so I could be way off...who knows?

Comment: What happens if you apply the material to the torus itself? What is the reason you subdivide the torus and not just increase its segments?

Comment: @AAGD  yeah I did that and it solved the problem. Still wondering why the subdivide-issue persist. Thanks alot!

Comment: @ngoductri a bit of a wild guess: maybe a connect object above the subdivision object can 'heal' the issues of the subdivision. Sorry, can't test, I only have R14.

Comment: @AAGD Man...Guess what. It did! thanks a lot senpai, I still have no clue whats really happening but it fixed it and i can move on, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that the object, or the object after subdivision, seems to consist of seperate parts that actually should be welded together. As far as I understand it, this is usually the job of the `Connect` object which does what its name implies: it connects the separated polygon objects.

It is also useful for extruded objects like text, where usually the caps are not connected to the rest of the shape.

So putting the torus (and the `Subdivison Surface` object) under a `Connect` object should result in a `watertight` object that behaves as expected to the applied materials.